# Having trouble dialing in a filter if statement - multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, filter

My desired functionality: 
Dropdown 1 = locations
Dropdown 2 = skills

when the user chooses a location from the dropdown and a skill from the other dropdown they will be presented with results (currently that works)

But the part im having trouble with is "All locations" & "All skills"
[note] I can't change the data bc its coming from an API

currently the page loads with no people (would be nice if the default was all locations all skills showing), and the dropdowns are set to "All locations" and "All skills, but i dont know how to make these states mean anything ,

or how to say "All locations" means you are looking at all the people , or the same for the skills

any help would be great. here is where I am so far 
my guess is this would be achieved with an if else statement, or a couple of them.. i dunno im starting to get confused

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      developers: [],
      filterCountry: "All locations",
      filterSkills: "All skills"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('API')
    .then(features =>  features.json())
    .then(developers => {
      this.setState({  developers })   
    })
  }

  filterCountry(e){
    this.setState({filterCountry: e })
  }

  filterSkills(e){
    this.setState({filterSkills: e })
  }

  render() {

    let developers = this.state.developers.features

    if (!developers ){
      return null
    }

   if  (this.state.filterCountry && this.state.filterSkills) {
      developers = developers.filter( developer =>
      developer.properties.continent
        .includes(this.state.filterCountry )
        )

     developers = developers.filter( developer =>
      developer.properties.skills 
        .includes(this.state.filterSkills )
        )

    }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

```
console.log(developers)
(20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
geometry
:
{coordinates: Array(2), type: "Point"}
id
:
"22bcd3917f78652cc62ee6908f057ceb"
properties
:
company_name
:
"redacted"
continent
:
"North America"
description
:
""
email
:
"redacted"
github
:
"redacted"
linkedin
:
""
location
:
"Sunnyvale, CA USA"

name
:
"redacted"
skills
:
""
skills_full
:
""
twitter
:
""
website
:
""
__proto__
:
Object
type
:
"Feature"
__proto__
:
Object
```

Comment: What does the shape of `developers` look like?

Comment: it changes at which point would you like to see ?

Comment: `this.state.developers` after the fetch is complete

Comment: let me know if an image of the console would be better, its  an array with all the developers in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to prevent filtering when the states are `filterCountry = "All locations"` and `filterSkills = "All skills"`

You can just do something like this in your filters:

```
developers = developers.filter( developer => { 
    return this.state.filterCountry === 'All locations' || developer.properties.continent.includes(this.state.filterCountry)
});
```

Comment: well thats the part that is a bit confusing.. like if north america is chosen.. and then all skills.. it still needs to filter for all the devs in north america ... does that make sense ?

Comment: Right, you would need to do the same thing in your other filter function.

Comment: seems to work well for locations, .. but not so much for skills.. like i will choose North American & all skills and that should show me all developers in north america but nothing comes up.. i need to play with it a bit more

Comment: did you add `return this.state.filterSkills === 'All Skills' || ...` to your skills filter function?

Comment: ah, it works now.. "All Skills" needed to be "All skills" ... thanks